# While working on binary image classification, the class mode set to binary incorrectly labels the images, but does it correct on categorical

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, image-classification, data-augmentation

I am currently working on a binary image classification. My problem is that when i use data augmentation, it incorrectly labels the images when it is set to binary.

The things i have tried:

- Looked for incorrectly labeled classes on images before augmenting my data. Here is nothing wrong however.
- Changed the class mode to categorical. This works, however i am not working on a multi-class classification.
- Tried playing with the image data generator. Nothing worked.
- Looked for classification imbalances. Also nothing wrong.

What could I try more? Should i just use categorical class mode on my generator?